# CSS Media Query Mobile vs Desktop: Mobile too zoomed out | Materialize

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, materialize

I have been using the materialize css framework to style most of my apps recently. When I loaded up the app I'm currently making on my phone it appeared way more zoomed out than it normally does. (See top two photos). The way it previously looked was much more zoomed-in and large (bottom two photos).

[image]

I've tried searching around for solutions but I'm not too sure what I'm looking for in terms of a setting that might be different between the two materialize releases or something.

Basically, how can I get my current site to render larger like the old one does? Is this in a media query somewhere?

I haven't changed my styling between these two apps. Really not sure what would have changed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing a viewport meta tag in your HTML?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Crap, I think you're right. Sorry for being so dumb! I'll test this once I'm back at PC.